# Custom SQL DateTime format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

The European format of dd/mm/yy hh:mm isn't supported by SQL, is there any way to create one? I am trying to return it in a stored procedure like so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetMeetingByCustomerID
    @CustomerID nvarchar(50),

AS

    SELECT  ProfessionalID, MeetingDate, Cost, HasReview, Approved
    FROM     Meeting
    WHERE  (CostumerID = @CostumerID)
    ORDER BY MeetingDate ASC
    RETURN
```

The only problem is that it returns it in the wrong format. 
Is there a way to create a new one? 
Thanks.
EDIT:
I solved this. what I did was:

```
 MeetingDate = DateTime.Parse(Meetings.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString());
                string d = MeetingDate.ToString("hh:mm dd/MM/yy");
```

Comment: Why do it in SQL? Do it in the application. What version of SQL Server (I am assuming that's what you are using)?

Comment: return it as a TO_CHAR with whatever format you like.

Comment: Agree with Oded.  Return an actual date, and format it in the application.

Comment: Most db's have date formatting functions.  Knowing the db engine you are using would help find them.

Comment: even if you wanted to use SQL to do this, why not look at the `CAST` and `CONVERT` sql Functions here's a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: `Formatting` a date is responsability of the application that gets the date back from your query, unless you try to return a character strings instead of a date

Comment: Here is an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) of how to set datetime format. And here is an [another article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) about how to *convert/cast* varchar to datetime or datetime to another datetime format.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I believe it's incorrect to format date/time in SELECT requests. But if you really need it, use [CAST/CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) (if you use MS SQL) and remove unused symbols like:

```
SELECT ProfessionalID, CONVERT (varchar(5), MeetingDate, 108) AS MeetingDateString, Cost, HasReview, Approved
FROM     Meeting
WHERE  (CostumerID = @CostumerID)
ORDER BY MeetingDate ASC
```

Comment: You'll want to alias the result of the `CONVERT`.

Comment: How can I do it in the application? im using c# and asp.net

Comment: @MichaelSallmen, yes sure, an alias should be there. I fixed my answer.
Htusa, formating depends on the control type you're going represent this information in. I'd recommend to go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx to get general information on formatting date/time in C#